# Replacing a word with a number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes

I have a table which has 12 columns containing a word, I want to change this to a number. For instance: each of these 12 columns can have one of 5 pre-specified possible values of:

- `highly agree`
- `agree`
- `no opinion`
- `disagree`
- `highly disagree`

I want to change these words with a number, the problem is the data type, it does not allow me to change a `nvarchar` data type to number, I even tried `text` data type to contain { highly agree, agree , no opinion , disagree, highly disagree } and then changed them to numbers but this error appeared:

> *Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1* 
>   *The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.*

The query I used was this:

```
[A1]= (case when [A1]='highly agree' then 1 
            when [A1]='agree' then 4 
            when [a1]='نظری ندارم' then 9 
            when [a1]='موافقم' then 16 
            when [a1]='کاملا موافقم' then 25 
            else [A1] end )
```

Comment: try to us `''` like `... then '1' ...`

Comment: What datatype is `A1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to convert your column to text data type, but you have to use your numbers as varchar in your case statement. You cannot mix up data types in the case statement

```
[A1]= (case when [A1]='highly agree' then '1' when [A1]='agree' then '4' when     [a1]='نظری ندارم' then '9' when [a1]='موافقم' then '16' when [a1]='کاملا موافقم' then '25' else [A1] end )
```

Further to your question, if you want to keep the calculation on this field then you have to cast the whole column to Number. As an example you can use this query

```
[CalculatedColumn]= CAST(case when [A1]='highly agree' then '1' 
                          when [A1]='agree' then '4' 
                          when [a1]='نظری ندارم' then '9' 
                          when [a1]='موافقم' then '16' 
                          when [a1]='کاملا موافقم' then '25' 
                          else '999' end ) AS INT) -- Any other number which can cast to integer
```

Comment: then is it possible to sum them or calculate the average of them??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SELECT (CASE A1 WHEN 'highly agree' THEN '1'
                 WHEN 'agree' THEN '4' 
                 WHEN 'نظری ندارم' THEN '9' 
                 WHEN 'موافقم' THEN '16' 
                 WHEN 'کاملا موافقم' THEN '25' 
                 ELSE A1
         END) AS A1
```